# Flash Player 10.0 r2 has stopped working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have developed my most complex Flash ActionScript app. I dont know how much complex they can get but I think mine is quite ordinary. it has about 1500 objects which are tween with zoom and colour changes only on click and connects to a database for data, eg, names of the objects are in a database. I have hard-coded the path to the web app that reads the database. The flash app reads the database from the web app (Visual Studio/server).

It works in my development environment (Flash CS4 > F12), with my required explores, ie, IE & FF.

However, when I try to run the the published version of it (.swf), which is in the same folder as the project, I simply get the error screen "Adobe Flash Player 10.0 r2 has stopped working", and nothing else happens. I am a little scared that I may have no way of publishing it for my client without having the whole code in the clients computer... Is there something I need to do to have it work in a server environment without Adobe Flash installed, ie, just the .swf file and the server settings with the database?

Note also that this worked when I started the project, when I was running a small file but as it grew bigger, even the debug mode stopped working...

I am running Win 7 64 bit, Flash CS4 and Visual Studio 2010 on my computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with the Adobe Flash Player web browser plugin you have installed, rather than a problem with your app or your swf. Try [upgrading the plugin](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

10.0 is a pretty old version by now, current version is 11.6. Also, it's a ".0" version, and 10.0 is known to have problems. It may or may not be important that your swf works in older Flash Players, including 10.0, but overall, not that many users have 10.0 installed today (http://www.statowl.com/flash.php).

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time,I have also meets up this issue, I found some root causes by using Vector class or invalid interfaces.